# binding 111 port fails in android application

Tags: android

In the Android application,call the native method by the `jni`  to create a `socket-server`.In native method, it failed in binding 111 port. when binding `8080` port,it successful.I don't know the reason,and how to resolve the problem.

---

in server.c file:

```
int start_server(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in s_add,c_add;
    int sin_size;
    unsigned short portnum= 0x6f;  // 111 port
    sfp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(-1 == sfp)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    bzero(&s_add,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    s_add.sin_family=AF_INET;
    s_add.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    s_add.sin_port=htons(portnum);
    // bind 111 port
    if(-1 == bind(sfp,(struct sockaddr *)(&s_add), sizeof(struct sockaddr)))
    {
        printf("bind fail !\r\n");
        return -1;
    }   

    if(-1 == listen(sfp,5))
    {
        printf("listen fail !\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("listen ok\r\n");

while(1)
    {
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    nfp = accept(sfp, (struct sockaddr *)(&c_add), &sin_size);
    if(-1 == nfp)
    {
        printf("accept fail !\r\n");
        return -1;
    }


    if(-1 == write(nfp,"hello,welcome to my server \r\n",32))
    {
        printf("write fail!\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("write ok!\r\n");
    close(nfp);
    }
    close(sfp);

    return 1;
}
```

in jni file  :

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_socket_SocketMain_startServer(JNIEnv *env, jclass thiz)
{
    if (start_server()<0) {

        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Port numbers up to 1024 are [reserved for root](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only).